# EF Core 2.1 Linq Query to EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am dealing with a query that i cannot get to work on ef core 3.0 and it worked fine in the 2.1 version, i would like if anyone can help figure how i can get it work in the 3.0 version.

So let me start with the challenge.

i have a table that is named Zone and it has a one to many relationship to a table called Bin, and bin has a one to many relationship to a table called BinItems, and BinItem has a one to one relationship to a table called PlanItem, and PlanItem has a one to one relationship with a table called Plan.

so i want to get a list of all plans in the plan table, but it must meet the condition that the plan items are in the zone of a specified list of zones. so let say i have a list of ZoneIds and i am looking for all plans that their related bin items is inside that Zones.

so here is my query that used in the 2.1 version and worked until migration to 3.0.

```
var filterQuery = _PlanRepository.Table;
filterQuery = filterQuery.Where(x => x.Items.Where(o => o.BinItem != null 
                                         && o.BinItem.Bin != null
                                         && o.BinItem.Bin.Zone != null)
                                 .Select(y => y.BinItem.Bin.Zone.Id)
                                 .Intersect(PlanFilter.WarehouseIds).Any());

var finalQuery = filterQuery
                     .Include(x => x.Items)
                           .ThenInclude(x => x.BinItem)
                           .ThenInclude(x => x.Bin)
                           .ThenInclude(x => x.Zone)
                           .AsQueryable();
```

now this gives me now an error like the following.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'Intersect(
>       source1: Select(
>           source: Where(
>               source: AsQueryable(MaterializeCollectionNavigation(Navigation: Plan.Items (k__BackingField, ICollection) Collection ToDependent PlanItem Inverse: Plan, Where(
>                   source: NavigationExpansionExpression
>                       Source: Where, Bin>, WarehouseSection>>(
>                           source: LeftJoin, Bin>, WarehouseSection, Nullable, TransparentIdentifier, Bin>, WarehouseSection>>(
>                               outer: LeftJoin, Bin, Nullable, TransparentIdentifier, Bin>>(
>                                   outer: LeftJoin, TransparentIdentifier>(
>                                       outer: Where(
>                                           source: DbSet, 
>                                           predicate: (p0) => Property>((Unhandled parameter: p), "Id") == Property>(p0, "PlanId")), 
>                                       inner: DbSet, 
>                                       outerKeySelector: (p0) => Property>(p0, "BinItemId"), 
>                                       innerKeySelector: (b) => Property>(b, "Id"), 
>                                       resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier(
>                                           Outer = o, 
>                                           Inner = i
>                                       )), 
>                                   inner: DbSet, 
>                                   outerKeySelector: (p0) => Property>(p0.Inner, "BinId"), 
>                                   innerKeySelector: (b0) => Property>(b0, "Id"), 
>                                   resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier, Bin>(
>                                       Outer = o, 
>                                       Inner = i
>                                   )), 
>                               inner: DbSet, 
>                               outerKeySelector: (p0) => Property>(p0.Inner, "ZoneId"), 
>                               innerKeySelector: (w) => Property>(w, "Id"), 
>                               resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier, Bin>, WarehouseSection>(
>                                   Outer = o, 
>                                   Inner = i
>                               )), 
>                           predicate: (p0) => Property>(p0.Outer.Outer.Inner, "Id") != null && Property>(p0.Outer.Inner, "Id") != null && Property>(p0.Inner, "Id") != null)
>                       PendingSelector: (p0) => NavigationTreeExpression
>                           Value: EntityReferencePlanItem
>                           Expression: p0.Outer.Outer.Outer.BinItem.Bin.Zone.Id
>                   , 
>                   predicate: (i) => Property>(NavigationTreeExpression
>                       Value: EntityReferencePlan
>                       Expression: (Unhandled parameter: p), "Id") == Property>(i, "PlanId")))), 
>               predicate: (o) => Property>(o.BinItem, "Id") != null && Property>(o.BinItem.Bin, "Id") != null && Property>(o.BinItem.Bin.Zone, "Id") != null), 
>           selector: (y) => y.BinItem.Bin.Zone.Id), 
>       source2: (Unhandled parameter: __PlanFilter_WarehouseIds_0))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ExpandNavigationsInExpression(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessWhere(NavigationExpansionExpression source, LambdaExpression predicate)

can anyone share how i can get this to work in Ef core 3.0 version?

Comment: This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: @tukaef thanks, i saw that, but my real issue is how can i deal with this, i just cant think how to get this to work again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, i figured it out.

here is my new code that works.

```
                query = query.Where(x => x.Items.Where(o => o.BinItem != null
                                                     && o.BinItem.Bin != null
                                                     && o.BinItem.Bin.Zone != null
                                                     && PlanFilter.WarehouseIds.Contains(o.BinItem.Bin.Zone.Id)).Any());
```